# Como obter informações de um certificado SSL via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, certificado-digital

Como obter informações (data de validade por exemplo) de um certificado SSL via C#?

Comment: Onde está o certificado? Dê mais informações do que você está tentando fazer. Algumas destas páginas te ajudam? http://www.a2zmenu.com/blogs/csharp/how-to-fetch-certificate-details-from-c-sharp-code.aspx e http://stackoverflow.com/q/2690082/221800. Se for isto, eu posso elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: @bigown é um cerificado https que fica em um servidor no qual eu referencio ele no meu website do IIS.

Comment: @bigown a que eu coloquei como resposta resolveu. Foi meio que um merge da sua, do cigano e da referência que coloquei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
public static void CheckCertificateExpiration(string[] args) 
    {
        foreach (string servername in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nFetching SSL cert for {0}\n", servername);
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(servername, 443);
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, callback, null);

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(servername);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            }

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    static RemoteCertificateValidationCallback callback = delegate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslError)
    {
        X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

        // Print to console information contained in the certificate.
        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", x509.Subject);
        Console.WriteLine("Issuer: {0}", x509.Issuer);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", x509.Version);
        Console.WriteLine("Valid Date: {0}", x509.NotBefore);
        Console.WriteLine("Expiry Date: {0}", x509.NotAfter);
        Console.WriteLine("Thumbprint: {0}", x509.Thumbprint);
        Console.WriteLine("Serial Number: {0}", x509.SerialNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Friendly Name: {0}", x509.PublicKey.Oid.FriendlyName);
        Console.WriteLine("Public Key Format: {0}", x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.Format(true));
        Console.WriteLine("Raw Data Length: {0}", x509.RawData.Length);

        if (sslError != SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: " + sslError);
        }

        return false;
    };
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826175/determine-ssl-certificate-expiration-date-iis)

Answer (score 9):

Conforme a [página](http://www.a2zmenu.com/blogs/csharp/how-to-fetch-certificate-details-from-c-sharp-code.aspx) que eu coloquei no comentário e a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) dá para pegar todas informações instanciando um objeto de certificado X509:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = @"Certificate:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
";
        var x509 = new X509Certificate2(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(texto));
        byte[] rawData = x509.RawData;
        WriteLine($"Content Type: {X509Certificate2.GetCertContentType(rawData)}");
        WriteLine($"Serial Number: {x509.SerialNumber}");
        WriteLine($"Friendly Name: {x509.FriendlyName}");
        WriteLine($"Certificate Verified?: {x509.Verify()}");
        WriteLine($"Simple Name: {x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true)}");
        WriteLine($"Signature Algorithm Name: {x509.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName}");
        WriteLine($"Public Key: {x509.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false)}");
        WriteLine($"Certificate Archived?: {x509.Archived}");
        WriteLine($"Subject: {x509.Subject}");
        WriteLine($"Issuer: {x509.Issuer}");
        WriteLine($"Version: {x509.Version}");
        WriteLine($"Valid Date: {x509.NotBefore}");
        WriteLine($"Expiry Date: {x509.NotAfter}");
        WriteLine($"Thumbprint: {x509.Thumbprint}");
        WriteLine($"Serial Number: {x509.SerialNumber}");
        WriteLine($"Friendly Name: {x509.PublicKey.Oid.FriendlyName}");
        WriteLine($"Public Key Format: {x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.Format(true)}");
        WriteLine($"Raw Data Length: {x509.RawData.Length}");
        WriteLine($"Certificate to string: {x509.ToString(true)}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KTgY9n). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D5luBA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Crypto.cs).

Além das propriedades a documentação mostra vários métodos que podem obter estas mesmas informações, como o [`GetExpirationDateString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getexpirationdatestring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate_GetExpirationDateString) para pegar o que você exemplificou.

Aí tem varias formas de pegar as informações como foi demonstrado. Como provavelmente não é só a data que você vai precisar, aí tem exemplos diversos, você vai usar o que e da maneira que for mais conveniente para você.

Answer (score 8):

Assim:

```cs
var certificate = new X509Certificate("C:\Caminho\Do\Arquivo", "senhadocertificado");
```

Um certificado SSL é um certificado do tipo X509. É também o mesmo tipo de certificado usado para assinatura digital em cartão (e-CPF, OAB, etc.) ou em token.

[Aqui você pode ver todas as informações possíveis de serem retornadas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). Basicamente, a data de validade se obtém assim:

```cs
var dataDeValidade = Convert.ToDateTime(certificate.GetExpirationDateString());
```

Caso queira, você pode usar a classe [`X509Certificate2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx).

Se o certificado estiver em um site remoto, ele pode ser obtido assim:

```cs
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://sitequesedesejaacessar");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
```